# before_body_end / google analytics isnt being rendered since upgrading to magento 1.9.1

Tags: php, magento, google-analytics, magento-1.9.1

I have a magento site which is built using the acumen/gravdept template. Google analytics used to work correctly, but since upgrading to 1.9.1 it has stopped working. The original version was 1.5.x

I am working in development mode, and I have disabled the options under cache storage management, turned off the profiler and flushed the magento cache and cache storage. I have even deleted the files under /var/cache.

I have tried copying `googleanalytics.xml` from the `base/default/layout` into my `gravdept/acumen/layout` folder and copying `base/default/template/googleanalytics` to `gravdept/acumen/template/googleanalytics` but that doesn't work for me.

I have also tried adding the following to `gravdept/acumen/layout/page.xml`

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
      ...
      <block type="core/text_list" name="before_body_end" as="before_body_end" translate="label">
        <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" template="googleanalytics/ga.phtml" />
      </block>
    </block>
  </default>
  ...
</layout>
```

I have `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>` in all of the page templates under `gravdept/acumen/template/page/`

Any help or advice would be great, I've spent hours on this and are going around in circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might enable that google analytics module in admin. 
Please check it if it was enabled : System->Configuration->Google Api->Google Analytics. 
That option should be enabled and set the account  number.

---

The correct answer was mentioned in the comments below. I ended up creating `frontend/gravdept/acumen/layout/googleanalytics.xml` with the following content.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <default>
    <reference name="after_body_start">
      <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" template="googleanalytics/ga.phtml" />
    </reference>
  </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Yes, its enabled. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Please replace the googleanalytics.xml with the following as :<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>

Comment: I tried replacing frontend/base/default/layout/googleanalytics.xml and that didn't work. I then created frontend/gravdept/acumen/layout/googleanalytics.xml and that didn't work also. I cleared all the magento caches before trying both. I also checked for <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?> which exists in my templates.

Comment: I just added template="googleanalytics/ga.phtml" to the <block> tag and this has worked. Thanks heaps for your help :)